# Problemas al actualizar serie de datos PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, tengo un modal donde me cargan las calificaciones de un alumno, si quiero actualizar esas calificaciones, solamente me actualiza el ultimo dato.
Adjunto imagen del modal [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También el código que tengo para eso actualizar en la página del modal es:

```
if(!empty($_POST['nota_act'])){
                    $id=limpiar($_POST['id2']);                     
                    $num = count($id);
                    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
                    {
                    $nota_act=limpiar($_POST['nota_act']);
                    $num1 = count($nota_act);

                print_r($id[$i].'<BR>');
                        for($z=0;$z<$num1;$z++)
                        {
                            print_r($nota_act[$z]);
                            $oActualizar=new Proceso_Calificar($id[$i],'','','',$nota_act[$z],'','');
                            $oActualizar->actualizar();
                        }
                    }
                        echo mensajes('Nota Actualizada con Exito','verde');

                }
```

Codigo del modal es el siguiente:

```
                        <div id="a<?php echo $row['periodo'].$row['materia']; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <form name="form5" method="post" action="">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            <h3 id="myModalLabel" align="center">
                                Modificar Notas <br>Materia "<?php echo $oMateria->consultar('nombre'); ?>"
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table table-hover">
                              <tr class="well">
                                <td><strong><center>Actividad</center></strong></td>
                                <td><strong><center>Nota</center></strong></td>
                              </tr>
                              <?php 
                                $paa=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM notas 
                                WHERE alumno='".$row['alumno']."' and periodo='".$row['periodo']."' and materia='".$row['materia']."'");                    
                                while($dato=mysqli_fetch_array($paa)){
                                    $oAct=new Consultar_Actividad($dato['actividad']);
                              ?>
                              <tr>
                                <td><input type="hidden" name="id2[]" value="<?php echo $dato['id']; ?>"><center><?php echo $oAct->consultar('nombre'); ?></center></td>
                                <td>
                                <input type="number" min="<?php echo $minima_nota; ?>" max="<?php echo $maxima_nota; ?>" value="<?php echo $dato['valor']; ?>" name="nota_act[]" autocomplete="off" size="4">
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <?php } ?>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><strong>Cerrar</strong></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><strong><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Actualizar</strong></button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

Y la clase en el archivo Clases.php es:

```
class Proceso_Calificar extends Conexiones{
var $id;        var $materia;      var $alumno;         var $actividad;     var $valor;
var $periodo;   var $fecha;

function __construct($id, $materia, $alumno, $actividad, $valor, $periodo, $fecha){
    $this->id=$id;              $this->materia=$materia;    
    $this->alumno=$alumno;      $this->actividad=$actividad;  
    $this->valor=$valor;        $this->periodo=$periodo;            $this->fecha=$fecha;
}

function guardar(){
    $id=$this->id;              $materia=$this->materia;    
    $alumno=$this->alumno;      $actividad=$this->actividad;        
    $valor=$this->valor;        $periodo=$this->periodo;            $fecha=$this->fecha;
    parent::__construct();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO notas (materia, alumno, actividad, valor, periodo, fecha) 
                              VALUES ('$materia','$alumno','$actividad','$valor','$periodo','$fecha')";
    $query = $this->conexion_db->query($sql);

}

function actualizar(){
    $id=$this->id;              $materia=$this->materia;    
    $alumno=$this->alumno;      $actividad=$this->actividad;        
    $valor=$this->valor;        $periodo=$this->periodo;            $fecha=$this->fecha;
    parent::__construct();
    $sql = "UPDATE notas SET valor='$valor' WHERE id='$id'";
    $query = $this->conexion_db->query($sql);

}
```

}

Pero sólo me guarda el ultimo dato en este caso la unidad 4 y las otras no.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código HTML del modal? ¿Estás seguro de que los datos se están enviando bien desde el modal al back-end? Aparte, si mandas 4 notas, en el código PHP compartido parece sólo leerse una (no hay bucle de ningún tipo ni múltiples lecturas), ¿Podría ser eso un problema?

Comment: Seria bueno que añadieras el código de la función limpiar. Aun easi los dos bucles for anidados son incorrectos y es lo que da el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los dos bucles for al insertar están mal planteados.

Si vemos el proceso para unidad 1 insertas las de la primera a la ultima que sera la quede. Lo mismo para la dos,la tres,...

Debería ser un solo bucle y tener alineados los id de elemento y nota.

Aquí tienes una ayuda del uso de arrays en forms http://php.net/manual/es/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Puedes usar por ejemplo un solo array de notas y poner en su índice  el id de la unidad.

Ejemplo:

```
Nota_act[6]
```

Luego recorres con un for de tipo clave=>valor e insertas cada valor a la clave que le corresponde.

Añado un ejemplo muy sencillo basado en tu código.

Para la pagina el loop de las notas seria:

```
<?php 
    $paa=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM notas WHERE alumno='".$row['alumno']."' and periodo='".$row['periodo']."' and materia='".$row['materia']."'");                    
    while($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($paa)){
        $oAct=new Consultar_Actividad($dato['actividad']);
        $name   = $oAct->consultar('nombre');
        $id     = $dato['id'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><center><?php echo $name ?></center></td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" min="<?php echo $minima_nota; ?>" max="<?php echo $maxima_nota; ?>" 
            value="<?php echo $dato['valor']; ?>" name="nota_act[<?php echo $id ?>]" autocomplete="off" size="4">
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Para el backend que graba las notas seria:

```
if(!empty($_POST['nota_act'])){
    foreach ($_POST['nota_act'] as $clave => $valor) {
        $id = limpiar($clave); 
        $nota = limpiar($valor);
        if(!empty($nota) || $nota == "0" ){ // empty evalua "0" como vacío
            $oActualizar=new Proceso_Calificar($id,'','','',$nota,'','');
            $oActualizar->actualizar();
        }
    }
    echo mensajes('Nota Actualizada con Éxito','verde');
}
```

Comment: Gracias Dubas!! Funciona a la perfección. Aprendí algo mas para mi mente